# Moment generating function and the distribution of compound variable.

Tags: probability

Assume that random variables $N,X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent and such that $X_i$ is (for each $i$) exponentially distributed with $EX_i=2$, $P(N=n)=2^{-(n+1)}$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Let $S=X_1+\ldots+X_N$ if $N>0$ and $S=0$ if $N=0$. Calculate $P(S<4\ln 5)$.

My work so far. The exercise can be easily solved by changing the order of integration and summation, after we appropriately write down $P(S<4\ln 5)$ as the sum of a series. However I can't use the following hint of the author of the exercise: "Notice that the moment generating function is of the form $p+ (1-p)\cdot \frac{a}{a-t}$". Could you help me please?

Comment: There are no $p$ and $a$ in your original problem.

Comment: The first step is to calculate the moment generating function of $S$.

Comment: Byron, thanks. But what is the next step? ;-) I would like to know before I start to calculate MGF. Please, give just the general idea.